# How to find most common element in list, and if there's a tie, the one who's last occurance is first?

Tags: python

Basically if given a list

```
events = [123,123,456,456,456,123]
```

I expect it *returns* **456** because 456 was last seen earlier than 123 was last seen.

I made lists comprised of the counts and indices of the initial list of numbers.
I also made a dictionary in which the key is the element from events (original part) and hte value is the `.count()` of the key.

I don't really know where to go from here and could use some help.

Comment: Let's start from the basics.  How would you do this with pen and paper?  What would you need to know, and what would you need to keep track of to satisfy this test condition?

Comment: If you know how to find the most common element in the list, and also know how to find which elements are tied, then you can search through the list in reverse (end to start) for the first reverse occurence of each element. Deepest into the list wins.

Comment: @Makoto, at least let's sum up that the current solution can determine the most common element, if there is not equality.

Comment: OP, good approach. The only issue is regular dictionary has no order. If you want to start from basic, given an input list, you will create a tuple (element, count) for each distinct element. What's the quickest way to get a set of distinct elements? Use `set`  `set(input_list)` and then count the number of occurrence for each element in that set.

Comment: I would need to know the positions and number of occurrences of each element in the list.  Then I would need to see if there is a tie for most common, and if so I'd pick the one that last occurred first.

Answer (score 5):

## Approach

Find the most frequently occurring items (Counter.most_common). Then find the item among those candidates that has the minimum index (enumerate into a dictionary of indexes, min of {index: key}.iteritems()).

## Code

Stealing liberally from @gnibbler and @Jeff:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_frequent_first(events):
    frequencies = Counter(events)
    indexes = {event: i for i, event in enumerate(events)}
    most_frequent_with_indexes = {indexes[key]: key for key, _ in frequencies.most_common()}
    return min(most_frequent_with_indexes.iteritems())[1]

events = [123,123,456,456,456,123, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
print(most_frequent_first(events))
```

## Result

```
>>> print(most_frequent_first(events))
456
```

## Code

A better piece of code would provide you with the frequency and the index, showing you that the code is working correctly. Here is an implementation that uses a named_tuple:

```
from collections import Counter, namedtuple

frequent_first = namedtuple("frequent_first", ["frequent", "first"])

def most_frequent_first(events):
    frequencies = Counter(events)
    indexes = {event: i for i, event in enumerate(events)}
    combined = {key: frequent_first(value, indexes[key]) for key, value in frequencies.iteritems()}
    return min(combined.iteritems(), key=lambda t: (-t[1].frequent, t[1].first))

events = [123,123,456,456,456,123, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
print(most_frequent_first(events))
```

## Result

```
>>> print(most_frequent_first(events))
(456, frequent_first(frequent=3, first=4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.counter`

```
>>> import collections

>>> events = [123,123,456,456,456,123]
>>> counts = collections.Counter(events)
>>> print counts
Counter({456: 3, 123: 3})
>>> mostCommon = counts.most_common()
>>> print mostCommon
[(456, 3), (123, 3)]
```

That's the hard part.

Comment: If you change the order and put the last 123 before any 456, still 456 would the first one to be shown, when it should be 123.

Comment: I don't think a `most_common()` can solve the question perfectly here because it returns the equal counts arbitrarily. You can't decide which is the last in the list.

Comment: This is (intentionally) not a complete answer. As the answer said, "That's the hard part." Ideally, Jeff would add logic for getting that last part done. A solid approach might be to create something subclassing both `Counter` and `OrderedDict` so you get the best of both worlds. (The list would have to be iterated through in reverse, though.)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> events = [123,123,456,456,456,123]
>>> c = Counter(events)
>>> idxs = {k: v for v,k in enumerate(events)}
>>> sorted(c.items(), key=lambda (k,v): (-v, idxs[k]))
[(456, 3), (123, 3)]
```

Comment: I don't think that this does the right thing. `>>> events = [123,123,456,456,456,123, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3] ... >>> sorted(c.items(), key=lambda (k,v): (v, idxs[k]))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (456, 3), (123, 3)]`

Comment: I believe you have to sort by descending count of occurrences and ascending index of last occurrence. This does the right thing: `>>> sorted(c.items(), key=lambda (k,v): (-v, idxs[k]))
[(456, 3), (123, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1)]`