# How to organize list by frequency of occurrence and alphabetically (in case of a tie) while eliminating duplicates?

Tags: python, frequency

Basically if given a list:

```
data = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "apple", "banana"]
```

I'm trying to make a function that returns a list like this:

```
["apple", "pear", "banana", "cherry"]
```

I'm trying to make the return list ordered by most frequently occurring word first while breaking ties by ordering them alphabetically.  I also am trying to eliminate duplicates.

I've made lists already of the counts of each element and the indices of each element in data.

```
x = [n.count() for n in data]
z = [n.index() for n in data]
```

I don't know where to go from this point.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Maybe you should see your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006404/how-to-find-most-common-element-in-list-and-if-theres-a-tie-the-one-whos-las/16006441#16006441

Answer (score 16):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "apple", "banana"]

counts = Counter(data)
words = sorted(counts, key=lambda word: (-counts[word], word))

print words
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer so far that has the tie-breaker the OP asked for.

Comment: I am a bit confused how in the sorted() function, the program understands "word" is associated with individual keys in the "counts" dictionary.

Comment: @Sean: `sorted(counts)` is the same as `sorted(counts.keys())`. It's ordering the keys (the words in `data`) according to `lambda word: (-counts[word], word)`. It's as if you replaced every key with `(-counts[key], key)`, sorted that list, and applied the resulting sorting to the keys themselves.

Comment: Is it by default that when the obj submitted to sorted() is a dict type, keys are being used to sort the list? I expected to see some form of "matching", e.g. [k:v for k,v in counts.items()] (To show what I meant by "matching"). I understand the lambda function takes the argument "word" to form sortable keys contain both the count and alphabetical info, but how does sorted() knows to submit individual dict keys into the lambda function and not individual dict values? The syntax seems a bit presumptuous in my beginner's eyes. Btw, great answer. So clever. I learned a lot from your code.

Comment: @Sean: It's not exclusive to `sorted`. Iterating over mappings (at least standard library ones) runs through their keys (with `list()`, `set()`, `tuple()`, a regular `for` loop, etc.). There are pros and cons to having dictionary iteration be over the keys versus the items, so I think it's just a choice that was made. There's probably some reasonable justification for it in a mailing list, but I'm not able to find any.

Answer (score 3):

For ordering elements by frequency you can use, `collections.most_common` documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections#collections.Counter.most_common), so for example

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "apple", "banana"]
print Counter(data).most_common()
#[('apple', 3), ('pear', 2), ('cherry', 1), ('banana', 1)]
```

Thanks to @Yuushi,

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "apple", "banana"]
x =[a for (a, b) in Counter(data).most_common()]

print x
#['apple', 'pear', 'cherry', 'banana']
```

Comment: +1, but to get it into the format the OP wants, you'd want to do a something like `x = [a for (a, b) in Counter(data).most_common()]`

Comment: I tried this at first, but `'cherry'` and `'banana'` are being switched around.

Comment: or: `from operator import itemgetter; x = map(itemgetter(0), Counter(data).most_common())` Also, this code does not implement the tie-breaker OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach, but it should work.

```
data = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "apple", "banana"]

from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

my_counter = Counter(data)

# creates a dictionary with keys
# being numbers of occurrences and
# values being lists with strings
# that occured a given time
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in my_counter.iteritems():
    my_dict[v].append(k)

my_list = []

for k in sorted(my_dict, reverse=True):
    # This is the second tie-break, if both
    # strings showed up the same number of times
    # and correspond to the same key, we sort them
    # by the alphabetical order
    my_list.extend(sorted(my_dict.get(k)))
```

Result:

```
>>> my_list
['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'cherry']
```