# Efficient method to determine the coherent pattern of words in lists of lists

Tags: python

Suppose I have these phrases stored in a list of words:

```
** school education high support level -->    support education high school level support
** school education high support level -->    support education high school level level education
** school education high support level -->    education high school level support education school
** school education high support level -->    support education high school level support
```

What is the most efficient way to compare the elements of a list of lists and pick the pattern that shares the most similarity with all the members?

```
[['support', 'education', 'high', 'school', 'level', 'support'],
['support', 'education', 'high', 'school', 'level', 'level', 'education'],
['education', 'high', 'school', 'level', 'support', 'education', 'school'],
['support', 'education', 'high', 'school', 'level', 'support']]
```

--- yields

[support, education, high, school, level]

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your comments and feedback. I was vague, and it got closed as not a "real question" though I think it would be more accurate to say it was not a fully articulated question.

(1) Definitely looking to maintain the **order of words**

(2) the criteria is a little more tricky than merely retaining the set of all elements that are present (i.e. set(A) & set(B) is not what I really want)

(3) Something more like the "set of all elements that are mostly present" with the word mostly being defined as some adjustable parameter, like present in 60% of cases, or 70% ...

I could write my own function (and I did) but it is slow and combersome. I assumed there had to be some trick from collections or itertools or similar module for grabbing this solution much faster. Like once I learned about Collections.Counter() my functions switched over and became much faster. I know there's a 'bag' or 'multiset' option but haven't used it to deal with the idea of a fuzzy set, where membership is defined by probabilities of being present across many examples of a thing.

That's why I asked - for feedback and insights into strategies along these lines.

Comment: base on what do you determine similarity? You can either use ``collections.Count`` or use set on all the lists ....

Comment: this might be useful. someone asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006404/how-to-find-most-common-element-in-list-and-if-theres-a-tie-the-one-whos-las

Comment: Your criteria are not clear. It looks like you're looking for the most common sublist in a list of lists. However, in this case, why would it not pick `["education", "high", "school", "level"]`, which (unlike your answer) appears in all four, or `["education", "high", "school", "level", "support"]`, which (just like yours) appears in three of them?

Comment: If you are interested in the order in which they appear you may want something like [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)...

Comment: Does each pattern have to be aligned to be similar?